# Is it possible to run a build.xml file which in turn executes another build.xml file

Tags: xml, eclipse, xslt, ant, build.xml

I have a build.xml file which has 5 targets. The last target depends on all the other targets. Is it possible to write all the targets in another build file and that can be given as "depends" value in the main build.xml file? So that when I run the main build.xml file it will inturn execute the other build.xml file which contains all the targets.

This is my Build.xml file:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<project name="Structure" default="Phone Setting"> 
    <target name="mailSetting">
        <xslt in="trial.xml" out="E:\Eclipse\Workspace\AntTrial\Output\res\com_email\values\conf.xml"
            style="trail_xslt.xsl">
        </xslt>
    </target>

    <target name="Camera Setting" >
        <xslt in="trial.xml" out="E:\Eclipse\Workspace\AntTrial\Output\res\system\values\conf.prop"
            style="camera_xslt.xsl">
        </xslt>
    </target>

    <target name="NFD" >
        <xslt in="trial.xml" out="E:\Eclipse\Workspace\AntTrial\Output\data\img\system-properties\conf.prop"
            style="nfd_xslt.xsl">
        </xslt>
    </target>


    <target name="Network Setting" >
        <xslt in="trial.xml" out="E:\Eclipse\Workspace\AntTrial\Output\data\img\system-properties\conf.prop"
            style="nfd_xslt.xsl">
        </xslt>
    </target>

    <target name="Phone Setting" depends="mailSetting,Camera Setting,NFD">
        <xslt in="trial.xml" out="E:\Eclipse\Workspace\AntTrial\Output\source\src\com_android\res\values\abc_conf.xml"
            style="Phone_xslt.xsl">
        </xslt>
    </target>

</project>
```

I need to place all these targets in another build.xml so that that file can be given as depends value.

Comment: Yes Of course its possible to use another build more than one target which must be executed. Please visit the link to know how to build a file other than build.xml. THat might help you.
[Link for building process](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html)

Comment: Yes, via `<import>` or `<include>`. See [_"How is <import> different from <include>?"_](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html)